# Is there a way for a plug-in to get it's own version number?

Tags: plugin-development

Is there an API I can call, inside my plug-in, to determine the plug-in's version?

I just want to have my plug-in emit a html comment with it's own version number ... for diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**@david**: Both @Adam Backtrom and @Viper007Bond give some good advice so I thought I'd take their advice and see if I couldn't implement something, see below.

What follows iS a plugin called ***WP Active Plugins Data*** that parses the header metadata for all active plugins anytime any plugin is activated and it stores all the metadata for each plugin into an array option in `wp_options`. I designed it for both regular WordPress plugins and multisite site-wide plugins. You can [**download it here from gist**](http://gist.github.com/525130) but I've also copied the code here for your review:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WP Active Plugins Data
Plugin URI: http://mikeschinkel.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-active-plugins-data/
Description: Loads Plugin Data on Plugin Activation and Persists to wp_options for quick retrieval.
Version: 0.1
Author: Mike Schinkel
Author URI: http://mikeschinkel.com
Note: Written for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/361/is-there-a-way-for-a-plug-in-to-get-its-own-version-number
*/

require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');

function get_active_plugin_version($plugin_path_file, $sitewide = false) {
    return get_active_plugin_attribute($plugin_path_file,'Version');
}
function get_active_plugin_attribute($plugin_path_file, $attribute) {
    $all_plugins_data = get_active_plugins_data($plugin_path_file,$sitewide);
    return (isset($all_plugins_data[$attribute]) ? $all_plugins_data[$attribute] : false);
}
function get_active_plugins_data($plugin_path_file, $sitewide = false) {
    $failsafe = false;
    $plugin = plugin_basename(trim($plugin_path_file));
    $sitewide = (is_multisite() && ( $sitewide || is_network_only_plugin($plugin)));
    if ($sitewide) {
        $all_plugins_data = get_site_option('active_sitewide_plugin_data',array());
    } else {
        $all_plugins_data = get_option('active_plugin_data',array());
    }
    if (!$failsafe && !is_array($all_plugins_data) || count($all_plugins_data)==0) {
        $failsafe = true; // Don't risk infinite recursion
        if ($sitewide) {
            $active_plugins = get_site_option('active_sitewide_plugins',array());
        } else {
            $active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins',array());
        }
        persist_active_plugin_data(null,$active_plugins,$sitewide);
        $all_plugins_data = get_active_plugin_version($plugin_path_file,$sitewide);
    }
    return $all_plugins_data[$plugin_path_file];
}
add_action('update_site_option_active_sitewide_plugins','persist_sitewide_active_plugin_data',10,2);
function persist_sitewide_active_plugin_data($option, $plugins) {
    persist_active_plugin_data(null,$plugins,'sitewide');
}
add_filter('update_option_active_plugins','persist_active_plugin_data',10,2);
function persist_active_plugin_data($old_plugins, $new_plugins, $sitewide=false) {
    $active_plugin_data = array_flip($new_plugins);
    $plugin_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR;
    foreach($new_plugins as $plugin) {
        $active_plugin_data[$plugin] = get_plugin_data("$plugin_dir/$plugin");
    }
    if ($sitewide)
        update_site_option('active_sitewide_plugin_data',$active_plugin_data);
    else
        update_site_option('active_plugin_data',$active_plugin_data);
}
```

Want to see how it works? Here's a test file you can drop in the root of your WordPress site (`http://example.com/test.php`.) Make sure you have both this plugin and Akismet activated before you test it.

```
<?php
/*
* test.php - Place in root of WordPress website.
*
* Before running be sure to activate both Akismet and the WP Active Plugin Data plugin
*
*/

include "wp-load.php";

header('Content-type:text/plain');
$akismet = "akismet/akismet.php";
echo "Akismet Version: " . get_active_plugin_version($akismet);
echo "\n\nAkismet Description: " . get_active_plugin_attribute($akismet,'Description');
echo "\n\nAll Akismet Data:\n";
print_r(get_active_plugins_data($akismet));
```

If it's not exactly what you need at least it should give you a good starting point. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. Nice job, Mike. I wonder how many plugins will come out of this StackExchange. :)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm hoping lots but I'm also hoping that only the best make their way into the repository. There is too much garbage up there right now!

Answer (score 3):

There is in the admin screens: `get_plugin_data()`. In templates, I think you will need the plugin to hold that data in PHP, e.g., set a constant or global or something, and keep that value synchronized with the plugin header version number.

`wp-settings.php` calls `wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()`, which pulls data from the `active_plugins` site option. This option only contains the path to the plugin file, and `wp-settings.php` only runs `include_once` on the file, so it's never parsed for the plugin metadata.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse your plugin's meta data (that stuff at the top of the file), but it's better for performance if you just set your own PHP variable with a matching version number. When you update the plugin, just update both version numbers.

It's slightly more work for you in the short term, but a lot better in the long term.

Comment: It may be better for performance to just define a variable but it is also not very nice to change the version number at 2 places.
For themes, there is a similiar function wp_get_theme that is even used in examples: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
It looks like a bad design in WordPress, it would be better if we could set the plugin version through a variable and then reuse the variable with wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script functions.

Comment: this is correct, however, this is one optimization would be negligible considering everything else Wordpress does on every request. In other words, it doesn't matter